# Play video when an image is clicked in html5 using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm a beginner of JavaScript. I want to play a mp4 file from a specific time for a certain time in HTML5. First, I want to load a thumbnail image. And if it is clicked, I'd like to play the video file from the particular time. This is my code. But it doesn't start from 6. It just starts from the beginning. What did I do wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function PlayVideo(anchor,vid, start_time, end_time, video_file) {
         document.getElementById(anchor).outerHTML = 
                 "<video id='" + vid + "' controls width='320'> <source src='" + video_file + "'              
                 type='video/mp4'/></video>"

        var video = document.getElementById(vid);

        video.play();
        video.currentTime = start_time;

        video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
            if(this.currentTime > end_time) {
                this.pause();
                this.currentTime = start_time;
            }
        });
        document.getElementById(aid).style.display = "none";
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="anchor" onclick="PlayVideo('anchor','003', 5, 9, 'test.mp4');"><img src ="test.jpg" alt="trail" /></a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look in your JavaScript console. (On Chrome press Ctrl+Shift+J.) Are there any errors? If so, post them in your question.

Comment: Thanks. There's a message like this: Uncaught Error: InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11. line 11 is "video.play();"

Comment: Add this line of code right after you set the video variable: `console.log(video);` and tell me what the value of `video` is. (Look in your console to find out)

Answer (score 1):

try

`document.getElementById(anchor).outerHTML = 
"<video id='" + vid + "' controls width='320'> <source src='" + video_file + "'

type='video/mp4'/></video>";`

Notice the

> **;**